# Testing UI with Screenshots

Tags: xcode, xcode9, xcode-ui-testing

I am trying to automate my testing a little. 
I wrote a simple test that takes a screenshot of my app

```
func testiPhoneVariants() {
    let screenshot = XCUIScreen.main.screenshot()
    let attachment = XCTAttachment(screenshot: screenshot)
    attachment.lifetime = .keepAlways
    add(attachment)
}
```

Now I wanted to test it on multiple simulators, so I made the command line:

```
xcodebuild -workspace MyProject.xcworkspace -scheme MyProjectUITests \
-destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone SE' \
-destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 7' \
-destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 7 Plus' \
-destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone X' \
test
```

The tests run through, but where can I find the screenshots?

Thanks
- Joseph

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also pass the `-resultBundlePath` to the `xcodebuild` command to specify where you want the test results to be.

```
xcodebuild -workspace MyProject.xcworkspace -scheme MyProjectUITests \
-destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone SE' \
-destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 7' \
-destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 7 Plus' \
-destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone X' \
-resultBundlePath test_results \
test
```

You should find in all your test results in the `test_results` folder. That also includes screenshots

Answer (score 0):

There will be an .xcactivitylog in your derived data folder, which is usually at the following path:

~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData//Logs/Test/

In the .xcactivitylog file, there will be objects containing details of your screenshot files including their filenames.